# Adding item to cart and removing from cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a + button to add item to cart,it works. But at the same time when number increments in cart I need number that says in stock will decrement number in stock that displays it doesn't work …

I need to do the same with - button

I really need the displayed `inStock` number to change when I add or remove items from cart
Can someone please help me? I'm new at this

```js
Vue.component('product', {

    template: 
    `
     <div class="product">
          
        <div class="product-image">
          <img :src="image" />
        </div>
  
        <div class="product-info">
            <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
            <p v-if="inStock">In Stock {{inStock}}</p>
            <p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
  
            <button @click="addToCart" 
              :disabled="!inStock"
              :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }"> + </button>

            <button @click="removeFromCart"> - </button>
  
         </div>  
      
      </div>
     `,
    data() {
      return {
          product: 'Hoodie',
          image: 'hoodie.jpeg',
          inStock: 10,
          cart: 0
      }
    },
      methods: {
        addToCart: function() {
            this.$emit('add-to-cart')
        },
        removeFromCart: function() {
             this.$emit('remove-from-cart')
        }
      }
  })
  
  var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        cart: 0,
        inStock: 10
      },
      methods: {
        updateCart() {
          this.cart  += 1,
          this.inStock -= 1,
        },
        removeItem() {
          this.cart  -= 1,
          this.inStock += 1
        }
      }
  })
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="nav-bar"></div>

            <div id="app">
            <div class="cart">
                <p>Cart({{ cart }})</p>
            </div>
            <product @add-to-cart="updateCart" @remove-from-cart="removeItem"></product>
            </div>
```

Comment: ```inStock -+ 1``` do you mean ```inStock -=1```? You also need to increase the stock in ```removeItem```

Comment: yes, meant inStock -=1

Comment: but still it doesn't work

Comment: you need to add ```inStock += 1``` to ```removeItem```

Comment: thank u, but still, I display this inStock, and when I add one to cart, that displayed inStock number doesn't change, it still shows 10

Comment: Are you sure, `updateCart()`/`removeItem()` are triggered? Also why did you duplicate the variable `inStock` in both the component and the root view? Maybe you're changing/displaying the "wrong" one ...

Comment: yes, I triggered them right. I dunno which inStock should I remove?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your component, remove the data attributes `inStock` and `cart` and `props` section.

```
Vue.component('product', {

    template: 
    `
     <div class="product">
          
        <div class="product-image">
          <img :src="image" />
        </div>
  
        <div class="product-info">
            <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
            <p v-if="inStock">In Stock {{inStock}}</p>
            <p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
  
            <button @click="addToCart" 
              :disabled="!inStock"
              :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }"> + </button>

            <button @click="removeFromCart"> - </button>
  
         </div>  
      
      </div>
     `,
    data() {
      return {
          product: 'Hoodie',
          image: 'hoodie.jpeg',
      }
    },
    props: {
      inStock: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      },
      cart : {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
      }
    },
      methods: {
        addToCart: function() {
            this.$emit('add-to-cart')
        },
        removeFromCart: function() {
             this.$emit('remove-from-cart')
        }
      }
  })
  
  var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        cart: 0,
        inStock: 10
      },
      methods: {
        updateCart() {
          this.cart  += 1,
          this.inStock -= 1,
        },
        removeItem() {
          this.cart  -= 1,
          this.inStock += 1
        }
      }
  })
```

Then in your parent component, pass the props.

**Parent Component (HTML)**

```
<div class="nav-bar"></div>

            <div id="app">
            <div class="cart">
                <p>Cart({{ cart }})</p>
            </div>
            <!-- changes for props added below -->
            <product :cart="cart" :inStock="inStock" @add-to-cart="updateCart" @remove-from-cart="removeItem"></product>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't know why but it shows  me out of stock because the default is 0, but still, it doesn't increment or decrement